# Padding around dates in R to add missing/blank months?

Tags: r, date, time-series, lubridate, padr

[The *padr* R pacakge vignette](https://edwinth.github.io/padr/articles/padr.html) describes different package functions to pad dates and times around said dates and times.

I am in situations where I'll be tallying events in data frames (ie `dplyr::count()`) and will need to plot occurrences, over a period of say... 1 year. When I count the events in a low volume data frame I'll often get single line item results, like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(padr)
df <- tibble(col1 = as.Date("2018-10-01"), col2 = "g", col3 = 5)

#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   col1       col2   col3
#>   <date>     <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 2018-10-01 g         5
```

To plot this with ggplot, over a period of a year, on a monthly basis, requires a data frame of 12 rows. It basically needs to look like this:

```
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>   col1       col2   col3
#>   <date>     <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 2018-01-01 NA        0
#>  2 2018-02-01 NA        0
#>  3 2018-03-01 NA        0
#>  4 2018-04-01 NA        0
#>  5 2018-05-01 NA        0
#>  6 2018-06-01 NA        0
#>  7 2018-07-01 NA        0
#>  8 2018-08-01 NA        0
#>  9 2018-09-01 NA        0
#> 10 2018-10-01 g         5
#> 11 2018-11-01 NA        0
#> 12 2018-12-01 NA        0
```

Perhaps `padr()` can do this with some combination of the `thicken()` and `pad()` functions. My attempts are shown below, neither line 3 nor line 4 construct the data frame shown directly above.

How do I construct that data frame direclty above, utilizing `padr()`, `lubridate()`, `tidyverse()`, `data.table()`, `base R`, or any way you please? Manual entry of each month shall not be considered either, if that needs to be said. Thank you.

```
df %>% 
  thicken("year") %>% 
  # pad(by = "col1") %>%       # line 3
  # pad(by = "col1_year") %>%  # line 4
  print()
```

Comment: Do you need the padded data frame?  You can plot in ggplot with a date axis and manual limits and it will show the whole year regardless of data.

Comment: @ Dan Slone maybe I shouldn't have mentioned ggplot. There's other parts of my analysis where I actually do need all the months, with the zeros, but thank you for that suggestion anyhow.

Comment: then `df2 <- tibble(col1 = seq(ymd('2018-01-01'),ymd('2018-12-01'), by = '1 month'))

merge(df,df2, by ="col1",all.y=TRUE)` would get you the output that you asked for - just need to change NA to zero if you so desire for col3

Comment: @Dan Slone thanks again for this suggestion. The problem is I can't be going in and manually adding months, as this solution requires. I need the code to be "smart enough" to recognize the year it's in, and pad around that year in increments of months. An added bonus would be if you could specify `# of months` to pad, or if you could pick some option such as `pad for the full year Jan-Dec` or `pad to fiscal year Oct-Sep`. I know the `pad to fiscal year` is quite a stretch. It probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Getting the year is pretty easy - see my updated answer below.  you would have to specify logic for fiscal year but that would be pretty easy as well.  pseudo-code would be `fiscal_year = if_else(month > 9,my_year + 1, my_year)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(col1 = as.Date("2018-10-01"), col2 = "g", col3 = 5)

my_year <- year(df$col1[1])

df2 <- tibble(col1 = seq(ymd(paste0(my_year,'-01-01')),ymd(paste0(my_year,'-12-01')), by = '1 month'))

df3 <- merge(df,df2, by ="col1",all.y=TRUE) %>% mutate(col3 = replace_na(col3,0))

df3
```